# i get the Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: java, android, listview

I don't know what is wrong with this code. I am trying to make a to do list app. I am new to Android and Java programming so please don't get mad if this is a simple errror.It gives me the error in the title.

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvItems"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="onAddItem"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etNewItem"
        android:hint="Enter a new item"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    private ListView lvItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //EditText
        final EditText etTask = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
        final String Task = etTask.getText().toString();


        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        items.add("First Item");
        items.add("Second Item");



        //Button
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        //Adding a Task


        //OnClickListeners
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                items.add(etTask.getText().toString());
                etTask.setText("");

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: You added two items **AFTER** the Adapter was assigned to the ListView (you should have done it **BEFORE**)! OK, it **is** possible, but then you **must** call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your Adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you made a change to adapter after ListView was populated, Listview must be informed to repopulate the views with new values by calling notifydatasetchanged() on your adapter ie,

```
 items.add(etTask.getText().toString());
 ((ArrayAdapter)lvItems.getAdapter()).notifydatasetchanged();
 etTask.setText("");
```

Comment: it says cannot resolve method notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: Sorry I forgot cast the adapter.

Comment: @Dale Glad I could help :)